# illegal path name using fileStream

Tags: vb.net

Trying to open a txt file using vb FileStream using filemode.open and fileaccesss.read (is a must).

But I keep getting "empty path name is not legal" and Im not sure why.

Full Code:

```
    Private Sub tsmOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsmOpen.Click

    Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim filePath As String = OpenFile.FileName
    Dim fileRead As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    OpenFile.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    OpenFile.Title = "Open Text Files"
    OpenFile.ShowDialog()

    Try
        Dim Read As New StreamReader(filePath)
        rtxtMain.Text = Read.ReadToEnd

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Read the code you posted line by line and think about how `filePath` can have a valid value at the point you use it to create the filestream.

Comment: oh I gave it the value before showdialog(), okay thanks!

Comment: The next thing you need to think about is why are you even creating the Filestream?  You are passing the `filepath` to the `StreamReader` constructor which is fine by itself, but if you opened the file previously, pass that stream reference instead.

Comment: It seems like your biggest obstacle to solving this yourself was the [lack of a rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (Eric Lippert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the event when the user closes the [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2). 
First you need to ask the user for a file, call the `ShowDialog()` method to retrieve the file if the `DialogResult` it's `OK`. 
Later then open the file with the `FileStream` in your specified path, creation mode and read/write permissions. 
I'm implementing the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using) statement to dispose the objects after it has been used.

```
    Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFile.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    OpenFile.Title = "Open Text Files"
    If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using fileReader = New FileStream(OpenFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(fileReader)
                rtxtMain.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

Another way to do that more simpler it's the [ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.filesystemproxy.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) method in [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.2) class:

```
    Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog With {
        .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt",
        .Title = "Open Text Files"
    }
    If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        rtxtMain.Text = File.ReadAllText(OpenFile.FileName)
    End If
```